# How to choose multiple options in a netlogo chooser?

Tags: netlogo, multiple-choice

I'm trying to choose multiple options from one chooser in netlogo. Does anyone know if that is possible and if it is how to do it?

Comment: Choosers can have lists as their options.

Comment: Can you explain more what you're after?

Comment: I have a slider which gives me a number of strategies I want. Those strategies I have to choose with a chooser. So if my slider gives me two, I have to choose 2 strategies etc.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use the [eXtraWidgets (`xw`) extension](https://github.com/CRESS-Surrey/eXtraWidgets), which allows you to define multichoosers like this:

[image]

A few words of warning:

- The extension only allows you to put that kind of widget on a separate interface tab.
- The extension is fairly powerful, but there is a bit of a learning curve to it: widgets need to be declared programmatically, you can't just drop them on the interface.
- As of today, the 6.x version of the extension is still in beta. The author has had limited time to iron out all the kinks.
- I am the author of the extension.

If `xw` doesn't meet your needs, you can most likely achieve what you want by using a series of switches, like this:

[image]

It's not quite as pretty and convenient, but it can get the job done.